# All items in my list update but i only want to add a single item

Tags: c#

In this script i sort my list with my own script and i want to add all the state of my list in a list of position

This is where i add my item in my list :

```
private List<int> values;
        public List<int> Values { get => values; private set => values = value; }
        static Position p;
        public List<Position> _lp;
        public Insertiontri()
        {
            _lp = new List<Position>();
        }
        public override void Sort()
        {
            int en_cours;
            int i, j;
            for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                en_cours = Values[i];
                for (j = i; j > 0 && Values[j - 1] > en_cours; j--)
                {
                    Values[j] = Values[j - 1];
                }
                Values[j] = en_cours;

                addValuesToPos();
            }
        }

        private void addValuesToPos()
        {
            List<int> ints = Values;
            p = new Position(ints);

            _lp.Add(p);
        }
```

And this is my class

```
public class Position
    {
        private List<int> _position;
        public List<int> position { get => _position; set => _position = value; }
        public Position(List<int> p)
        {
            position = p;
        }

    }
```

and the Values is generated with this function

```
public override void Random()
        {


            Values = Enumerable.Range(1, 20)     // la plage de nombres dans ta collection,
               .OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())   // ordonné par rapport à un guid,
               .ToList();

            _lp.Add(new Position(Values));
        }
```

Comment: `P` is static and it's also just a pointer to one instance of `Position`. You add that pointer over and over. You store new object at that address but it's a unique address. P, is the shoe box near the door. Every one enter the house and place their shoes in the shoe box. At the end of the day there is only one pair in this box. But everyone knows that their shoes is in that box. Change `_lp.Add(p);` by `_lp.Add(new Position(ints))`.

Comment: I just change the acces modifier of P and it still change the value of all the item in my list what should i try to do ?

Comment: The issue is not with static. I just talk about it because it make less sense. Static means that the shoes box is not only common for everyone entering the house but for any instance of house in the town “static” means relative to "_the type itself rather than to a specific object_" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static.

Comment: But the static and the small part of code you gave me dont change nothing

Comment: Saddly you had an other shoes box named `Values` in your shoes box.  `P`. `List<int> ints = Values;` => `List<int> ints = new List<int>(Values);`. I will just reconsider the whole thing. fixing this one should fix everything as every P  will have a new inner box and it's just a transition variable that is used to send new value into the list of position

Comment: Thank you so much I dont understand all about pointer. But know it work thank you man

Comment: Shoes box was my best try to illustrate the reference issue. Here is a short cleanned up version of your code https://dotnetfiddle.net/9sbezB. may be easier to understand with a reduce complexity. Ou je peux le faire en francais si jamais. Mais c'est juste une histoire de boite et de trucs dans la boites.

Comment: Looking at your new question, it's perhaps time to reintroduce Position complexity. But in an usefull way. what if `Position` is not just a  `List<int>`, but instead it store the current value of `i`, and `j`. That way you will know what value you where comparing and the index of the swap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the same `List<int>` for all the Positions.

In order to simplify and illustrate the issue we need to do some clean up. We will remove Position that is just a wrapper around `List<int>`.And remove unnecessary properties.

We have a class that store a `List<int>` and a list of snapshoot of that list at each step or the sorting process.

```
public class SortingAlgo_StepByStepDemo {   
    public List<int> Source {get;set;}  
    public  List<List<int>> Steps {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

The Sorting algorytm and implementation stay the same.
We just need to change the way we stored the picture/snapshoot of the "step".

```
public void SaveStep()
{       
    // It's the same.
    // Steps.Add(Source.ToList());
    Steps.Add(new List<int>(Source));
}
```

If we had `Steps.Add(Source)` like you had. It will save not a picture but the reference for the actual List source. And every elements of Steps will just point to the same thing.

Live demo : https://dotnetfiddle.net/9sbezB

---

I added a Ctor that take a `List<int> Source`. So you can test on fixed Input.